# Row Deletion ADO.Net, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am trying to work with a contact list and want to remove all of the info on a person when I type in their name. I am using a sql table -named Contact- that contains the Name, Email and Address of a contact. I have the following code:

```
    protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnect"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string delete = "DELETE FROM Contact WHERE Name =" + NameToDelete.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(delete, con);



        try
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", delete);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("ViewContacts.aspx");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }


    }
```

When I use this, it seems to be comparing the column Name to the name I am putting in. So the name Bill is being compared against the column header Name instead of what is in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use single quotes around the values with var(char) types. If you don't use quotes it will think that you are referencing a column name instead of value.
It's valid for all databases, following is from oracle docs:

> character literals are enclosed in single quotation marks, which
>   enable Oracle to distinguish them from schema object names.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/sql_elem.htm

```
string delete = "DELETE FROM Contact WHERE Name ='" + NameToDelete.Text + "'";
```

Actually what you are trying to do is using sqlcommand parameter, then you need to use parameter name using @[ParameterName] in sql statement.

```
string delete = "DELETE FROM Contact WHERE Name = @Name";
```

Comment: That's true if you add the parameter ensure that you use it! If you don't plan to use it,  there is a lot of code that does not have sense!

Comment: @AntonioRodriguez you are right, i realized that parameter usage after those lines. The preferred way is ofcourse using parameters for security reasons (against sql injection).

Comment: Alright, I messed around with it a bit and I got it to work with parameters.AddWithValue("@NameToDelete", NameToDelete.Text); Seems to be a lot cleaner this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your problem is that you are using the variable delete in two instances.  First for create the command that is fine and second as the parameter value,  which is wrong.  In the parameter value probably you must use the value tthat you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You have several serious problems with your code.

1. Your connection is never closed or disposed. Use Using blocks which will close and dispose of database objects even if there is an error.
2. You are concatenating a string to get your Sql statement risking Sql injection and damage to your database.
3. You are adding a parameter to your command when there are no parameters in your Sql statement.
4. You are using .AddWithValue which takes the parameter name and the parameter value as arguments. You have provided your entire Sql statement as the value of @Name. This should be NameToDelete.Text.
5. Do not use .AddWithValue. Use .Add(parameter Name, Sql data type).Value = value of parameter. This can speed up queries and avoids type mismatches in the database.
6. If name is your Primary Key, you are OK, but if not you should delete by the primary key or send all values in the Where clause.

   ```
   protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnect"].ConnectionString))
       {

           string delete = "DELETE FROM Contact WHERE Name = @Name;"; //no single quotes to worry about
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(delete, con))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NameToDelete.Text; //just guessed at the VarChar - check your database for type
               try                  
               {           
                   con.Open();
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   Response.Redirect("ViewContacts.aspx");
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Response.Write(ex.Message); //ex by itself, will get you nothing but the fully qualified name of Exception
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```